# Confluent Control Center Interceptor

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

How do I add Confluent Control Center Interceptor to an existing S3(Sink) Connector? To monitor the Sink. I am looking for documentation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where's the data coming from? Have you also enable interceptors on the Producer of the data?

Comment: No, currently Interceptors are not on any of the Producers. Just want to implement interceptors on S3(Sink) Connector.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/   Quick start documentation shows properties that can be used for any connector https://docs.confluent.io/current/control-center/docs/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be absolutely clear, you need interceptors on your sink ***and* source**. If you don't, you can't monitor your pipelines with Confluent Control Center as it stands today.

To enable interceptors in Kafka Connect, add to the worker properties file:

```
consumer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor
producer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor
```

If you're running it in distributed mode then the worker config file will be `etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties`.

Comment: Moffat, are there any other dependencies that I need other than below?

`<dependencies>
  ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-cp1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>monitoring-interceptors</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  ...
 <dependencies>`